# Why youtube not allowed autoplay=1 & controls=1?

Tags: javascript, iframe, youtube, youtube-api

[screen non load video](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DCuYL.png)[image]

I need open video in popup with autoplay and controls bar, but my code not working.
Try

```
var player;
    function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady(code) {
        if(player){

        player.destroy();
        }
    player = new YT.Player('iframe', {
        videoId: code,
        playerVars: {
            'autoplay': 1,
            'fs': 0,
            'enablejsapi': 1,
            'showinfo': 0,
            'loop': 0,
            'controls': 1,
        },
        events: {
            'onReady': onPlayerReady
        }
    });

}

function onPlayerReady(event) {
   event.target.setVolume(100);
    event.target.playVideo();
        
}
```

And remove/add iframe

```
$("#iframe").html("<iframe width='100%' height='100%' id='ytiframe' frameborder='0' src='//www.youtube.com/embed/"+code+"?autoplay=1&autohide=1&controls=0&showinfo=0&rel=0' allowfullscreen=''></iframe>");
```

For all version work autoplay OR controls.

My question on YouTube forum [Not upload video from api with parameters autoplay and controls in true.](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/youtube/vFWvbbh9kfo;context-place=forum/youtube)

**Answer!**
it was because block for iframe must be visible. If insert iframe after method show(), slideDown(), fadeIn() - all working.

Comment: I don't think anyone on stack overflow can tell you why google chooses to allow  or disallow features in there APIs.

Comment: It completely depends on which enviornment your player is loaded..... For me the problem was video-fullscreen option was not present in android app.... However it was present for chrome browser.....

Comment: Thanks for answer. But it was because block for iframe must be visible. If insert iframe after method show(), slideDown(), fadeIn() - all working.